# Read data from a text file and store it in an array of objects - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, regex

### Objective

I want to make this program so that it can read from a text file and store the data into an `Array of Objects`.

The format shown below is the format this text file will be in, **if possible the space after commas should be trimmed, but not the full string.**

So when, this program runs it will push the content into an array which can be used later in the program as `array.map()`.

### Sample Text File

```
//file.txt (Note: The main file will always be in this exact format)

John Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077 
Jane Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077
Arlong Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077
Mark Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077
Bill Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077

// format: [ firstname lastname, date of birth (MM/DD/YYYY), Address, City, State, Zip]
```

### Desired OutPut

```
array = [
  {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    dob: '01/30/2000',
    address: 'This is the Address',
    city: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    zip: "70077"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Jane",
    lastname: "Doe",
    dob: '01/30/2000',
    address: 'This is the Address',
    city: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    zip: "70077"
  },
  {
    firstname: "Arlong",
    lastname: "Doe",
    dob: '01/30/2000',
    address: 'This is the Address',
    city: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    zip: "70077"
  }
] //and so on
```

Comment: It's seems like your `file.txt` is actually a CSV-file, and should be treated like so, use a proper csv parsing library. Maybe something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse

Comment: @andlrc, It is a .txt file. I do not understand what you meant by it being csv. Thank you

Comment: Each value is separated by a comma so it can safely be classified as a **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alue file. There exist standard parsers which deal with these types of files. The firstname and lastname combo would require additional processing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

You can get a csv parser but if you are sure this is the format you can save some kilobytes

```js
const csv = `John Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077 
Jane Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077
Arlong Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077
Mark Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077
Bill Doe, 01/30/2000, This is the Address, Los Angeles, CA, 70077`

const obj = csv.split(/\n/).map(line => {
  const [name, dob, Address, City, State, Zip] = line.split(", ")
  const [firstname, lastname] = name.split(" ");
  return { firstname, lastname, dob, Address, City, State, Zip: Zip.trim() }
});

console.log(obj)
```